# Error installing eclipse (jvm.dll load error) - how to fix?

Tags: windows, eclipse, failed-installation

I am trying to install Eclipse inside a virtual machine running Windows 7 64-bit.

When I launch **eclipse-inst-win64.exe**, I get the following error: **Failed to load the JNI shared library "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.2\bin\server\jvm.dll**.

Both eclipse and JDK are 64-bit.

The DLL is there:

```
c:\>dir "c:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.2\bin\server\jvm.dll"
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 8E3B-94B
 Directory of c:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.2\bin\server
07/27/2019  04:47 PM        11,538,912 jvm.dll
```

Java is 64-bit:

```
c:\>"c:\Program Files\Java\
jdk-12.0.2\bin\java.exe" -version
java version "12.0.2" 2019-07-16
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 12.0.2+10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 12.0.2+10, mixed mode, sharing)
```

No other JDK or JRE versions are installed.

Java itself works just fine - I compiled and ran few Spring samples, installed and used Maven, everything works.

Any idea what can be wrong here? Is there any way to force Eclipse to output more info about the error (e.g. the value returned by GetLastError() in the Windows API after loading the library failed).

Thanks!

Comment: Just wrote a simple C program for trying to load jvm.dll. It appears the DLL cannot load because "VCRUNTIME140.dll" is missing from the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by downloading and installing the Visual C++ 2015 runtime from Microsoft.

Apparently it's needed for that specific jvm.dll and isn't installed automatically by the JDK installer.